# Issue to get the raw body with Sveltekit only when deploying on Vercel

Tags: stripe-payments, vercel, sveltekit

I'm trying to set up Sveltekit, Stripe and Vercel. It works correctly on a local environment and also when deployed on node server (heroku) but when I deploy it to Vercel I get this error message (400):

```
{"msg": "Webhook Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing"}
```

Here the request code and the svelte.config.js

```
export async function post({ request }) {
    let event;

    try {
        const sig = request.headers.get('stripe-signature');
        const rawBody = request.Buffer();
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, sig, STRIPE_HOOK_ENDPOINT_SECRET);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {
            status: 400,
            // @ts-ignore
            body: { msg: `Webhook Error: ${err.message}` }
        };
    }
```

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
    }
};

export default config;
```

Can't find nothing around regarding this issue using SvelteKit and Vercel. I tried also other solutions to access rawBody but everyone works except with Vercel Adapter:

- locally (works)
- Vercel cli locally (works)
- deployed using adapter-node on Heroku (works)
- deployed on Vercel (not works )

If you have encountered a similar one or have a suggestion to share would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Andrea

Comment: if it works in a local environment with the same code, I might try adding some logs for the production environment. So for example, log the value of `rawBody` and check that it matches the type of thing you see in local (should be a string that matches the Stripe event JSON you see in the Stripe dashboard).

Comment: Also, note that the webhook signing secret is different for every URL/endpoint you have in your Stripe account. So for example maybe your configuration in production is wrong and you're using the `whsec_xxx` secret for a different Stripe endpoint, or the one that is logged from `stripe-cli`, instead of the correct secret from the dashboard page in Stripe where you created the production URL. Or you might just have a typo/missed copy-paste character in the secret value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately the rawbody is not exposed on Vercel and the api key are correct as they works everywhere (locally and with Node ).
Any attempt to access the rawbody returns undefined on Vercel.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/1303 or https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/1294 could help

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
const sig = request.headers.get('stripe-signature');
const buffer = Buffer.from(await request.arrayBuffer()); // <----
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buffer, sig, STRIPE_HOOK_ENDPOINT_SECRET);
```

Comment: it doesn't work